# Font awesome not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap, less, font-awesome

I'm using bootstrap and I added font awesome through Less, overriding the Glyphicons. The icons display OK in chrome but in Firefox i just see boxes.

This is how my directory looks like

```
-- Project
  -- js
  -- css
  -- less
  -- font-awesome
    -- css
    -- font
    -- less
```

All I've modified in the `Project > less > boostrap.less` file has been:

```
@import "sprites.less";

//for this line

@import "../font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
```

As I said in Chrome works fine but for some reason Firefox shows only boxes.

Comment: Are you using CDN? Take a look at CORS.

Comment: have you removed `@import "sprites.less";`??

Comment: yeah, with what @ShankarCabus said. You'll want to look into how to use CORS with what ever server you're working with. You might need to set some headers with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to be `*` or whatever the domain is.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Custom web fonts via CDN (or any cross-domain font request) doesn't work in **Firefox** or **Internet Explorer** (correctly so, by spec) though they do work (incorrectly so) in Webkit-based browsers.

You can fix this by adding headers to your page.

Apache

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Nginx

```
if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Credit: http://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts

Comment: Any solution for IIS ?

Comment: I dont understand. How is one supposed to change the headers in Apache, if the files are being loaded from a remote CDN? (I know the OP is loading locally, but you appear to be talking about CDNs)

Comment: It's easier and faster just setting : 
"<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">"

Using you method @Dustin Brownell it doesn't works locally in a html projects.

Comment: @Blackersoul : It won'twork unless local html project is served through some kind of server, under ```http://localhost```

Comment: Its just as the comment above says. It won't display unless your project is served through some kind of server. As soon as i deployed my project locally the icons appeared just as they did on chrome.

Answer (score 24):

If you want a quick and easy way to make Font-awesome work, try using [CDNJS](http://cdnjs.com/). It's free and powered by CloudFlare. CORS is supported out of the box.

Try something like this:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Premjg it worked perfectly for me - whereas fiddling with httpd.conf did nothing to solve my problem. This was indeed the simplest solution!

Comment: This should be the chosen answer since it works in many other situations (I'm building my site with jekyll)

Comment: In a commercial project which is security is important (such as bank website), you don't want to use CDNs at all unless you want customer's browser send referrer to 3rd party websites.

Answer (score 10):

If you are hosting the font on S3, you have to [enable CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) on the bucket. Through AWS Management Console, edit the properties for the bucket and under Permissions click on "Add CORS Configuration". In my case, if I left the default config, it still didn't work, so I changed it to:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Here is a good link I found on how to do this: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-

Answer (score 6):

I was having issue with the if statement because I didn't have a $filename variable.

But I did have similar results using:

```
location ~ /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
```

Comment: I am using Nginx 1.4 and this was the better approach than the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Using a CDN as premjg suggested is the least invasive method besides hosting it yourself. The latest version of fontawesome [suggests bootstrapcdn](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/), e.g.,

`<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

As a minor note, noscript silently blocks requests to the CDN unless whitelisted, *and* it won't prompt you to whitelist the CDN unless your page also requests JS files from the same domain.

Comment: @FirstLast - I reverted your edit since unconditional forcing of 'htpps` protocol is not always a good idea (learn what is "impicit protocol URL").

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me, modifying a web.config file is something you're not allowed to touch.

Try storing all the font files (.eot, .ttf, etc) into their own local folder, and link to them locally instead of the FontAwesome CDN. Cleared it up in IE and FF for me every time.

```
@font-face{ font-family:'FontAwesome'; src:url('../_fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wordpress and you think you've tried everything, look and see if you ever installed a **Font Awesome plugin.** Disable the plugin and refresh in Firefox.

This was the solution for me - the plugin's older version of font-awesome was overriding the files I was trying to update myself manually.

Answer (score 0):

In fonts folder please upload the following files

> FontAwesome.otf
>   fontawesome-webfont.eot
>   fontawesome-webfont.svg
>   fontawesome-webfont.ttf
>   fontawesome-webfont.woff
>   **------------------ Important glyphicons files----------------**
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Please upload the following files and after that you link your font-awesome.min.css in your header file.

Here is the following link with proper files:
http://goo.gl/WICQAf