# Font Awsome Icons not resolving with assets_base_urls

Tags: symfony, font-awesome

I am trying to configure the assets paths for my symfony2 application. I use the following 
`asset_base_urls` in `config_prod.yml`

```
framework:
    templating:      
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_base_urls: http://example.com/mysymfony2app/web/
```

The fontawesome icons display as expected when i type in the browser `http://example.com`
However, when I add `www` as in `http://www.example.com`, the icons do not display.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or  a better implementation?

Comment: Are you sure that the URL with or without `www` points to the same directory? What is the errer message, an 404 error?

Comment: Yes they point to the same directory. No error as such, all other assets display(e.g images) with the exception of fontawsome icons.

Comment: Go directly to the URL of the image to see the error.

Comment: Firebug does not give any error messages. I need to emphasize, all other assets render just fine, that is images and css. It is only fontawesome icons that have an issue.

Comment: How are the icons displayed? Are they called from a CSS file? Do you use a filter with Assetic? Please show examples of code of a *showing* image and one that doesn't show. How did you export the assets?

Comment: ok. I think i got it. seems to be a browser issue, firefox being the culprit. All other browsers(IE, Chrome, Blackberry browser) work just fine. I am unable to post an answer to the question as I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Found out has nothing to do with symfony in the first place.
It is related to this issue: [Font awesome not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866872/font-awesome-not-working-in-firefox)

The answer given fixes it.