# Font Awesome not working in Firefox although hosted on the same domain

Tags: firefox, heroku, fonts, font-awesome

I have this problem: [Font awesome not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866872/font-awesome-not-working-in-firefox)

But no one there explained *why* there's a need to play with CORS settings even though the fonts are hosted on the same domain.

```
/index.html
/fonts/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.*
```

They're being imported using `@font-face()`. Works fine in Safari/Chrome.

One thing to keep in mind is this is being hosted on Heroku, but is also happening on localhost.

**Again, the question is why do I have to allow access control even though the domain is the same?**

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same trouble.

The fastest way is simply using the cdn link :

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I really don't know exactly what's the problem but I read that **happens because there's a CORS configuration issue.**

I've just **solved using the CDN**