# Where is the .htaccess on OVH server?

Tags: .htaccess, font-awesome

So, I have a website hosted on OVH and the icons of Font Awesome are not displaying on Firefox. Upon research, I have found that there is a [simple way to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866872/font-awesome-not-working-in-firefox).

However, here's my problem : My site is hosted on an OVH server, and I was not able to find the .htaccess file. I went through the files with Cyberduck (on Mac) in my www directory on the server, and have not been able to find the file to add the code.

Comment: Maybe you should just create it?

Comment: Haven't tried yet, maybe that could work but I thought there would be some config files somewhere and I would just have had to modify this one

Comment: There's generally no pre-made `.htaccess` files on shared hosting (the default config is directly done in Apache's venvs) and you'll certainly need to create it the first time

Comment: So, yeah, I'm not gonna answer my own question but this was indeed the solution : create a .htaccess file containing the snippet of code show in the link in my question, and placing this file in the folder containing the font. Thx !

Comment: That's pretty much how it works!