# Font awesome not showing just one icon in firefox, but in chrome is working perfectly

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-awesome

I have this [webpage](https://www.eworkbox.com/landingpage/), it works smoothly with chrome, but with firefox, the right arrow is not showing, I am using font-awesome, and tried this answer in this post [Font awesome not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866872/font-awesome-not-working-in-firefox) with no success.

I am using CDN to call font awesome, so the fonts are in their server, the strange thing is that is only in firefox the problem.

I am using Ubuntu Linux 16.04, and firefox 52.0.1 (64-bits)

Please could someone tell me how to deal with firefox and this strange issue?

UPDATE: the issue happens with firefox in Linux and Windows

Comment: I can see the arrow on my Firefox browser.

Comment: Are you using windows or linux? @SimrandeepSingh

Comment: I am using mac OS

Comment: I use linux, I haven't tried on Windows or mac, but in Linux  with firefox the right arrow is not showing up

Comment: On Windows 10, Firefox 51, the arrow is not showing...

Comment: Then somebody else might be able to help you as I don't have linux installed here on my system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info with the mac OS anyways

Comment: Please add a [mcve] using something like jsbin, or an in-post html+css+js snippet, so we can see what you're trying to achieve, because the answer you posted for yourself is *definitely* not the right answer (`%` and `vw` are completely different types of units and you can't substitute one for the other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the CSS for firefox is pretty different to the other web browsers, I had to do this:

Cange this:

```
.next-prev-cities-titles {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none
}
```

For This:

```
.next-prev-cities-titles {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none
}
```

Firefox wasn't taking the 100% width

Comment: You could have just done `right: 0;` also, which is more "correct" with the absolute positioning. And just dropped the width (and height, but that would have meant a `bottom: 0;` as well)

Comment: `100vw` is not the same as `100%` at all. 100vw are absolute dimensions based on the viewport's width. No matter how small the element's parent is, 100vw is always the same length, and so anything with 100vw that is inside another element will pretty much guaranteed overflow. On the other hand, 100% is "100% of the parent element" (or, really: of the closest ancestor with a `position` set, ending at `<body>`). So you've made a change that does something *completely different*, and just happens to *look* like it's what you need. But it's not a fix, it's a new bug =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so you can help with the correct solution instead of marking the negative post

Comment: probably, if there's a [mcve] to work with. Without that, we'd have to guess at the HTML and CSS that's actually involved (we're not going to sift through an entire website, [it's on you](/help/how-to-ask) to reduce your problem case to something you can post as part of your question). That said, I downvoted because this solution makes it seem like `100%` and `100vw` are mutually interchangeable which is almost *never* the case, so even if this works for you, right now, it's a terrible answer for others who might run into this question later (remember: SO posts are not just for you)